# Is it possible to change the path where visual studio looks for moc-files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I´m using Visual Studio 2010 with Qt 4.8.2 and the Qt Add-In.
My project is composed of four sub-projects, so the "GeneratedFiles"-folder is created for every single sub-project. I tried to put all generated files (like moc_*.cpp, ui_*.cpp) in one folder (GeneratedFiles/Release), which worked just fine by changing the qt-project-settings via the Add-In in VS.
 When I try to build now, however, the moc-files aren´t found and I get the following error for every moc-file:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: "Release\moc_writerappender.cpp": No such file or directory

So it´s looking in "Release" instead of "GeneratedFiles/Release", which I can´t seem to change. After some serious searching I don´t know where to look anymore.
Where do I change that folder? Is it even possible?

Comment: did you have a look at your project files (open it with an editor like notepad++)? Searching the Qt stuff in the project settings is a bit annoying, since much of those are hidden in custom build step settings etc. In the project file itself they can be searched with your editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your include directories.

1. Right click on the project in the solution explorer and click on the menu option "Qt Project Settings"
2. Chose directories to put each type of file ( .moc, .ui etc). Press Ok
3. Right click on project in the solution explorer and click on the menu option "Properties".
4. Click the "C/C++" tab, then the "General" sub tab. Add those directories into your Additional Include Directories section.
5. Make sure you do this for each applicable configuration ( debug, release etc).

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, sorry. I already tried that several times in every variation I could think of. The folder in which VS is searching doesn´t change, however.